# Spring Hibernate : No matching bean of type org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting the below error in my spring mvc appliation, I have looked up the same error code on stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked and thus posting it here again. I think its an issue with some/few jars not loading but I am not sure.

I have pulled my brains out but no luck.. Hoping someone else can point out where I am going wrong.

I am getting an error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 58 more

Aug 25, 2016 5:18:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [springmvc] in web application [/springmvc] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
```

I have hibernate jars in my maven pom.xml

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.java.bricks</groupId>
  <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency> --> 

<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency> 

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springmvc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I also have my session factory defined in my springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.bricks" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<!-- view resolver -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

<!-- start database related changes -->

    <!-- dataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="{database.url}"></property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="{database.driver}" />
        <property name="username" value="{database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="{database.password}" />
     </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.java.bricks.entity.EmployeeEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
             <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>    
            </props>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

<!-- end database related changes -->


</beans>
```

and the springmvc-servlet.xml is in the web-inf/config directory as indicated in the web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Spring MVC Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I am using the sessionFactory in the employeedao with autowired anotation

```
package com.java.bricks.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.java.bricks.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.java.bricks.entity.EmployeeEntity;

@Repository("employeedao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addEmployee(EmployeeEntity employee) {
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(employee);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<EmployeeEntity> listAllEmployees() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EmployeeEntity.class).list();
    }

    public void updateEmployee(EmployeeEntity employee) {
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(employee);
    }

    public EmployeeEntity getEmployeeEntity(Integer id) {
         return (EmployeeEntity)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(EmployeeEntity.class,id);

    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Integer id) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM EmployeeEntity where EMPID = "+id).executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

Update 1:

adding employeeEntity.java

```
package com.java.bricks.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7086842712981602982L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="EMPID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="EMPNAME")
     private String name;

    @Column(name="EMPAGE")
     private Integer age;

    @Column(name="SALARY")
     private Long salary;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
     private String address;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change class name of sessionFactory bean to

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

in spring config file

Comment: yes I had this earlier but when I had the session factory as "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"   I get an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.<init>(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:93)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0

Comment: thanks changing to annotation and then downloading the hibernate-annotations.jar worked.